# Failed Upgrade of Ubuntu 22.04 from Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation

I attempted to update my Dell M90 to Ubuntu 22.04 from Ubuntu 20.04.  The update progressed until it got to a certain point where I started to received the following errors (also see attachment) over and over again.

["142.707268]   NVRM:  The NVIDIA Quadro FX 2500 GPU installed in this system is supported through the NVIDIA 304.xx Legacy drivers.  Please visit https://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html for more information.  The 470.223.02 nvidia driver will ignore this GPU.  Continuing probe.....

I went to driver website but I don't know what to do to get back to a point where I can troubleshoot.  Should I re-install Ubuntu 20.04?  I then attempted to install Ubuntu 23.10 from a flash drive using Rufus and still hit a dead end.  I had to reinstall Linux Mint 19.2 and once I installed (diskette 19.2), the install went through with no issue.  My Dell M90 is an older laptop and maybe that's the issue but the failed installs either ended with a gray/black striped screen or stopped activity.  There's obviously a difference in Linux Mint 19.2 and the latest issues of Ubuntu 23.10.  There's a difference that's worth looking into.

[image]

Comment: I received a screen with black and white stripes or the process froze as mentioned previously mentioned.